# Cut data (seasonal component)

Tags: r

I'm looking for R code which cut my data.
My initial data looks like that : 
[image]

Here are the first 300 rows :

```
c(0.096, 0.088, 0.082, 0.078, 0.06, 0.057, 0.048, 0.047, 0.044, 
0.044, 0.039, 0.038, 0.037, 0.037, 0.035, 0.035, 0.034, 0.034, 
0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.2, 1100, 
1100, 27, 15, 3.2, 2.2, 1, 0.65, 0.37, 0.3, 0.19, 0.16, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.099, 0.096, 0.085, 0.082, 0.064, 0.06, 0.051, 0.05, 0.046, 
0.045, 0.041, 0.041, 0.039, 0.038, 0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 
0.034, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 
0.028, 4.4, 1100, 1100, 120, 21, 9.4, 3.1, 1.6, 0.85, 0.51, 0.33, 
0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.092, 0.085, 0.077, 0.065, 
0.058, 0.053, 0.05, 0.047, 0.045, 0.043, 0.042, 0.039, 0.038, 
0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.031, 
0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 
0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 37, 1100, 98, 17, 6.2, 2.7, 1.3, 
1, 0.47, 0.31, 0.23, 0.16, 0.14, 0.11, 0.1, 0.093, 0.087, 0.079, 
0.066, 0.057, 0.053, 0.049, 0.046, 0.044, 0.041, 0.04, 0.037, 
0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 
0.027, 0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 2.6, 1100, 1100, 190, 
22, 7.8, 3.2, 2.2, 0.91, 0.51, 0.37, 0.23, 0.18, 0.14, 0.12, 
0.11, 0.098, 0.09, 0.085, 0.071, 0.061, 0.055, 0.051, 0.049, 
0.045, 0.043, 0.04, 0.039, 0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 
0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 
0.028, 0.028, 0.027, 0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 
0.026, 8.8, 1100, 160, 21, 7.5, 3.4, 1.6, 0.89, 0.52, 0.33, 0.23, 
0.17, 0.14, 0.13, 0.1, 0.094, 0.087, 0.078, 0.065, 0.056, 0.051, 
0.049, 0.045, 0.043, 0.039, 0.039, 0.036, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 
0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 
0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 
0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 13, 1100, 170)
```

And here is data structure :

```
> dput(head(.data))
structure(list(y = c(0.096, 0.088, 0.082, 0.078, 0.06, 0.057), 
    x = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

And if I zoom on it :
[image]

And the result I would like to have is this (this graphic only represents the first 300 rows. I didn't use any algorithm ) :

[image: https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/05/06/190506024354598169.png]

I tried to cut my data with this algoritm :

```
find_cycle <- function(x, y) {
  dy <- diff(c(0, y))
  cut(
    x = x,
    breaks = c(min(x), which(dy > mean(dy) + 3 * sd(dy)), max(x)),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    right = FALSE
  )
}
.data <- .data %>%
  mutate(cycle = find_cycle(x, y)) %>%
  group_by(cycle) %>%
  mutate(x_cycle = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup()

p <- ggplot(data = .data, mapping = aes(x = x_cycle, y = y, colour = cycle)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position='none')

p
```

But the result is not what I expected :
[image: https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/05/06/190506024847486945.png]

Do you have some idea ? Thanks.
I apologize for not being word-perfect in English.

Comment: Would you mind in give us an example of your data? you might use `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` if it is huge. Also, would you explain better what you mean when you say "cycle data". You may tell us what kind of data you are using. As in bioinformatics, if you work with the prokaryote genome you probably have "a circular data" since the genes on circular genome aways have 1 at left and another at right.

Comment: These are industrial data. I can't tell your more (professional secrecy).

Comment: I guess I should say "Cyclical behavior" ? Here is a link which illustrate the process (cutting data) I'm looking for : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/05/06/190506053618257180.png

Comment: no problem, but you insert the first 300 rows, where I sow only one column. If you use `dput(head(df))` you will send only 10 rows but with data structure making easy to understand what you want. Also, you may explain better. What is "cut data into cycle"? For me, it seems that you just need to `group_by` some parameter. Also possible directly within ggplot when you use the `color` parameter within aesthetics `ggplot(aes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis, color = some_grouping_colum)`.

Comment: This least, you may be adding `geom_hline()` to reproduce the green lines.

Comment: I've just added data structure.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is "superimpose peaks". One peak for each cycle

Comment: each cycle is one data frame?? because you might do this in the same plot call different `geom_`. Would you mind in add the plot command you are using? If it is, you might bind all df and add a column which will identify each set of values, and within aesthetics you use color.

Comment: No. There is only one data frame. Data contains several cycles which we define. What I'm trying to do is identify these cycles by dividing data. Every cycle has the same size (around 10 seconds).

Comment: Each cycle contains only one "peak".

Comment: I think "cycle" is not an appropriate term. I should say "season component" or "seasonality".

Comment: And "spikes" instead of "peaks".

Comment: You should add a column to identify each season, that means, each 10s. Since you cannot explain your data we cannot show how to do that unless you use fake data with the same behavior of yours to explain the problem. But let to say you have any method to identify the rows belong to the same cycle or season, you might add a 3rd column with any tag to identify it, this way you will be able to color them, to add a line cutting each season you might manually add it with `geom_vline` or identify from your data each point of x-axis in your data which represent the end of each season.

Comment: Also, it seems that you create the x line but you didn't report it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function only works if you have a previous x-axis. Which was only possible to know how you build it based on your data structure.
But seems everything is working.

```
d <- tibble(y = c(0.096, 0.088, 0.082, 0.078, 0.06, 0.057, 0.048, 0.047, 0.044, 
  0.044, 0.039, 0.038, 0.037, 0.037, 0.035, 0.035, 0.034, 0.034, 
  0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 
  0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.2, 1100, 
  1100, 27, 15, 3.2, 2.2, 1, 0.65, 0.37, 0.3, 0.19, 0.16, 0.12, 
  0.12, 0.099, 0.096, 0.085, 0.082, 0.064, 0.06, 0.051, 0.05, 0.046, 
  0.045, 0.041, 0.041, 0.039, 0.038, 0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 
  0.034, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 
  0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 
  0.028, 4.4, 1100, 1100, 120, 21, 9.4, 3.1, 1.6, 0.85, 0.51, 0.33, 
  0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.092, 0.085, 0.077, 0.065, 
  0.058, 0.053, 0.05, 0.047, 0.045, 0.043, 0.042, 0.039, 0.038, 
  0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.031, 
  0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 
  0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 37, 1100, 98, 17, 6.2, 2.7, 1.3, 
  1, 0.47, 0.31, 0.23, 0.16, 0.14, 0.11, 0.1, 0.093, 0.087, 0.079, 
  0.066, 0.057, 0.053, 0.049, 0.046, 0.044, 0.041, 0.04, 0.037, 
  0.036, 0.035, 0.035, 0.033, 0.033, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 
  0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 0.028, 
  0.027, 0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 2.6, 1100, 1100, 190, 
  22, 7.8, 3.2, 2.2, 0.91, 0.51, 0.37, 0.23, 0.18, 0.14, 0.12, 
  0.11, 0.098, 0.09, 0.085, 0.071, 0.061, 0.055, 0.051, 0.049, 
  0.045, 0.043, 0.04, 0.039, 0.037, 0.036, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 
  0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 
  0.028, 0.028, 0.027, 0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 
  0.026, 8.8, 1100, 160, 21, 7.5, 3.4, 1.6, 0.89, 0.52, 0.33, 0.23, 
  0.17, 0.14, 0.13, 0.1, 0.094, 0.087, 0.078, 0.065, 0.056, 0.051, 
  0.049, 0.045, 0.043, 0.039, 0.039, 0.036, 0.035, 0.034, 0.033, 
  0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 
  0.027, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 
  0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 13, 1100, 170))

d <-  d %>% mutate( x = row_number() )

find_cycle <- function(x, y) {
  dy <- diff(c(0, y))
  cut(
    x = x,
    breaks = c(min(x), which(dy > mean(dy) + 3 * sd(dy)), max(x)),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    right = FALSE
  )
}
d %>%
  mutate(cycle = as.character(find_cycle(x, y))) %>%
  group_by(cycle) %>%
  mutate(x_cycle = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_cycle, y = y, colour = cycle)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]